# Could HDD recovery require more than one donor drive?

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery, hard-drive-recovery

When my HDD started corrupting data I took it to professional drive recovery service. I was told that it was hardware failure and donor drive is required. Donor drive would be used for parts to replace faulty parts in original drive. I provided donor drive with exact model number and all seemed well. However, today I received status update that the donor drive was "used up" and another donor drive would be required.

**Is it normal that more than one donor drive would be required for hard disc recovery?**

My concern is that it could have been their fault that donor drive died or whatever that "used up" means. I wouldn't want to have to provide yet another donor drive or pay fortune for their services of finding a matching donor drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, it is not usual.

If it is a problem that can be solved by swapping parts over from one drive to another, you will only need that one part in order to make the faulty drive work (providing the donor drive was in perfect working order).

If the error is with a controller board, spindle or motor, how will having two spares work?

It sounds to me like they may have broken something... or, if you could, please get more information from them.

Comment: That's what I thought as well. I wanted to be sure that one donor drive should have been sufficient before going to discuss it with them. I'll post updates after I get more information.

Comment: Sounds like they messed up and managed to break something, and don't want to buy another themselves.